# Problema com Google Charts + AngularJS + ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Estou desenvolvendo um SPA com AngularJS, e estou realizando alguns testes com Google Charts, porém, estou tendo um problema que não estou conseguindo identificar o porquê. Ao logar na aplicação, o usuário é redirecionado para a página de início em uma ng-view, onde há 3 gráficos, 1 de coluna, 1 de pizza e 1 de linhas. A primeira vez, carrega tudo normalmente, porém, ao trocar de página, e retornar para a de início, o gráfico de linhas está sendo redimensionado, ficando pequeno, os outros estão corretos, somente o de linhas que está apresentando esse problema. Mais alguém já teve esse problema? 
[image: Antes de navegar]

[image: Após navegar]

Comment: Você por acaso não está definindo um `width`em algum lugar ou inserindo um elemento paralelo ao chart?

Comment: Não, o meu div onde está sendo renderizado o gráfico é somente `<div id="exemploChart"></div>` dentro de um `<div class="tab-panel">`, inclusive experimentei colocar um `width: 100%` ou definir um tamanho fixo mas também não resolveu, e na instância do chart coloquei apenas um `height: 250` nos **options**.

Comment: Posta o código amigo.

Comment: Consegui resolver, era uma dependência do JarvisWidget que estava faltando, mas não exibia nenhum tipo de erro, após revisar todo o código, ele funcionou normalmente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era uma tag do JarvisWidget que estava faltando, após revisar todo o código, comparar com um funcional e inserir a tag ausente (`<section id="widget-grid">`), ele funcionou normalmente.